# What commands are available from inside tmux choose-tree?

Tags: tmux

If I press `Ctrl-B + s`, tmux gives me a nice overview of open sessions:

[image]

What commands are available from this screen besides `Enter`, which allows me to switch to the selected session? E.g. can I terminate or rename a session directly from this screen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default binding for <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> is:

```
bind-key -T prefix s choose-tree -s
```

So it's indeed about `choose-tree`. This is what the [manual](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#choose-tree) says:

> ```
> choose-tree [-GNrswZ] [-F format] [-f filter] [-O sort-order] [-t target-pane] [template]
> ```
>
> Put a pane into tree mode, where a session, window or pane may be chosen interactively from a list. `-s` starts with sessions collapsed and `-w` with windows collapsed. `-Z` zooms the pane. The following keys may be used in tree mode:
>
> ```
> Key    Function
> Enter  Choose selected item
> Up     Select previous item
> Down   Select next item
> x      Kill selected item
> X      Kill tagged items
> <      Scroll list of previews left
> >      Scroll list of previews right
> C-s    Search by name
> n      Repeat last search
> t      Toggle if item is tagged
> T      Tag no items
> C-t    Tag all items
> :      Run a command for each tagged item
> f      Enter a format to filter items
> O      Change sort field
> r      Reverse sort order
> v      Toggle preview
> q      Exit mode
> ```
>
> After a session, window or pane is chosen, `%%` is replaced by the target in template and the result executed as a command. If template is not given, `switch-client -t '%%'` is used.
>
> `-O` specifies the initial sort field: one of `index`, `name`, or `time`. `-r` reverses the sort order. `-f` specifies an initial filter: the filter is a format - if it evaluates to zero, the item in the list is not shown, otherwise it is shown. If a filter would lead to an empty list, it is ignored. `-F` specifies the format for each item in the tree. `-N` starts without the preview. `-G` includes all sessions in any session groups in the tree rather than only the first. This command works only if at least one client is attached.

Not all keys work in older versions of `tmux` though. Refer to `man 1 tmux` in your OS.

---

> can I terminate or rename a session directly from this screen?

- Terminate – yes, with <kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd>.
- Semi-directly, with <kbd>:</kbd> and the desired command, e.g.:

  - <kbd>:</kbd>`rename-session -t '%%' foo`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
  - <kbd>:</kbd>`kill-session -t '%%'`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Or you can invoke/bind your own variant of `choose-tree` that will kill session(s) with <kbd>Enter</kbd> thanks to a "killing" template you provide:

  ```
  choose-tree -s "kill-session -t '%%'"
  ```

Note you can run a command for multiple items; you just need to tag them with <kbd>t</kbd> first. This can be useful with `kill-session`, maybe less useful with `rename-session`.

Comment: Looks like X is available in the latest version of tmux: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html. So it would depend on your version.

Comment: @JonathanReez True. My answer has been updated.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use "-t %%" when using : in tree mode because the default target will be the currently selected pane, window or session.